# Powershell Script Reads CSV File twice

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I currently try to read a CSV file, adjust the given data to a powershell command and write it in an other file. 
Problem:
The forEach-Loop, which goes through the CSV file loops twice. Therefore the outputfile contains the output twice.

```
function ReadCSV($file_path, $delimeter, $UserInputUser, $UserInputPw){
$data=Import-CSV -Path $file_path -Delimiter $delimeter
$destinationPath=Find-Folders
ForEach($dataset in $data) {
    $username=$dataset.$UserInputUser
    $pass=$dataset.$userInputPW
    if(($username -gt 0) -AND ($pass -gt 0)){  
        WriteOutputFile -username $username -pass $pass -destinationPath $destinationPath
    }
}
#Run ReadOutputFile function
ReadOutputFile -destinationPath $destinationPath }
```

I think the forEach-Loop seems to be the problem. I have currently no clue how to solve this problem.

Here is the WriteOutputFile

```
function WriteOutputFile($username, $pass, $destinationPath) {
    $createUserComand="New-LocalUser -Name ""$username"" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString ""$pass"" -AsPlainText -Force) -Confirm"
    #write-output $createUserComand | add-content -path $destinationPath\output.ps1
    $createUserComand | out-file -filepath $destinationPath\output.ps1 -Append
}
```

Comment: I assume that `WriteOutputFile` is a custom function. What is it doing? Your `foreach` loop tries to call it on every iteration.

Comment: You can also replace your `foreach` and `if` loop combination with `where-object` like `$outputData = $data | Where-Object {($_.$UserInputUser -gt 0) -and {$_.$UserInputPw -gt 0}}`. However, I am not exactly sure what your `WriteOutputFile` function is doing.

Comment: **PLEASE** do not paste code in comments because that is unreadable. Instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59102921/edit) your question and paste the code in there

Comment: I added the WriteOutputFile function to the question